# Got hired but never went to work

Tags: hiring

I recently did an interview at a electronic shop. I filled out a physical form with my previous employment and all my other information. Then on the same day the manager did the interview and he said you are hired and they gave me a another form to fill out like my address, and social security etc. to do a background check.  They called me to come in the next week but I never went. Also, I don't want to go to this job.

So, my question is, does that mean I get fired?

Comment: I think there is an issue of clarity here, possible due to some language barriers. It is not clear to me if the OP is asking if they still have the job (obviously not), but rather if this is considered as being "fired" for other purposes (such as government issues, answering "have you ever been fired" on job applications, etc).

Comment: Did you actually accept the offer?

Comment: Why do you care? You evidently didn't care much for the job in the first place so I don't see where the question is coming from. What you did constitutes "walking off the job" which is tantamount to quitting. It's often referred to as "no call, no show". If this is about unemployment or something like that, this wouldn't constitute being fired (or fired for cause if anything). There's a good argument to be made that you were never actually hired anyway.

Comment: If I were an employer and a new hire simply didn't show up on day one without informing us, and I couldn't reach them to find out what happened, I'd terminate them and they'd be on my records as having been fired.  Since you're not going to put this job on your resumé, it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 5):

I would say you definitely were not fired, because you never went to work for the company, so they could not fire you.

However, *the company may terminate you ( fire you ) due to not showing up*.  I would suggest you call and tell them your not coming to work for them.

Comment: If it were me I would mark him as terminated for no call no show so he can never be hired again. You're considered hired when you accept their offer not your first day showing up.

Comment: At least for purposes of HR matters like this one vs. things like benefits and government stuff.

Comment: @BirdLawExpert Noted, answer updated.  ( and I agree )

Comment: @Paparazzi What don't you agree with?  The first part of my answer ( not fired ) or the second part ( company could )

Comment: I may have misread.  Never mind.  +1

Answer (score 1):

I seriously doubt you were even officially hired.  When you arrive is when they would officially put you in payroll and HR.   I would not consider you as ever actually employed by the company.

Comment: His start date came and went, he was officially hired. He failed to show up. no call no show. It's different than an offer rejected status which happens before your start date.